# Calculating Processing and Request time for multiple Asynchronous Requests

Tags: ajax, performance, jquery, time, benchmarking

For data visualization request in my application, I am sending multiple AJAX requests to a servlet in order to get the data in chunks and on callback of each request, the data received is rendered over map.

For this request, I am trying to calculate:

- Request Time (how much total time it took for client to get data from server)
- Processing Time (how much total time it took for client to render the data on client side)

In order to do this, I am capturing start time of each request before sending it to server (using jquery "beforeSend") and "onSuccess" event of each request, the end time is captured.

Once the all requests are completed, I am deducting the "start time" of first request from the "end time" of last request in order to calculate the total time the client took for fetching records from server. (Similarly for Processing Time)

But somehow my calculation doesn't produce correct results. Could any one please provide me some suggestions for this issue?

for explaining my question in more better way:

```
var dataProviderRequestsStartTime = [];
var dataProviderRequestsEndTime = [];

var dataParsingStartTime = [];
var dataParsingEndTime = [];

getResults(ids);

var getResults = function(totalIds) {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++;) {
       requestResultForOneChunk(totalIds[i]);
        }
};

var requestResultForOneChunk = function(streetIds) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            var requestStartTime = new Date().getTime();
            dataProviderRequestsStartTime.push(requestStartTime);
        },
        type : 'POST',
        url : "myServlet",
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data : {
            "ids" : streetIds,
        },
        success : function(response) {
            //Request Finished
            var dataProvideRequestEndTime = new Date().getTime();
            dataProviderRequestsEndTime.push(dataProvideRequestEndTime);

            addFeaturesToMap(response);
        },
        error : function(x, e) {
            alert("Something went wrong in the request" + e);
        }
    });
};

var addFeaturesToMap = function(measurements) {
    //Parsing Started
    var featureParsingStartTime = new Date().getTime();
    dataParsingStartTime.push(featureParsingStartTime);

    doParsing(measurements);

    //Parsing Finished
    featureParsingEndTime = new Date().getTime();
    dataParsingEndTime.push(featureParsingEndTime);
};

$("#loading").bind(
        "ajaxStart",
            function(options) {
                ajaxStartTime = options.timeStamp;
            }).bind("ajaxStop", function(options) {
        var ajaxEndTime = options.timeStamp;
        var totalTime = (ajaxEndTime - ajaxStartTime);
        calculateTimeBreakDown();
});

var calculateTimeBreakDown = function() {
    var totalValues = dataProviderRequestsEndTime.length;
    var lastValueIndex = totalValues - 1;

    // Request Time calculation
    var endTimeOfLastRequest = dataProviderRequestsEndTime[lastValueIndex];
    var startTimeOfFirstRequest = dataProviderRequestsStartTime[0];
    var totalRequestTime = (endTimeOfLastRequest - startTimeOfFirstRequest);

    // Parsing Time Calculation
    var endTimeOfLastParsing = dataParsingEndTime[lastValueIndex];
    var startTimeOfFirstParsing = dataParsingStartTime[0];
    var totalParsingTime = (endTimeOfLastParsing - startTimeOfFirstParsing);
};
```

Finally, I have requestTime(totalRequestTime) and parsingTime(totalParsingTime). But the problem is adding these both doesn't produce value near to total time which is calculated using ajax start and stop.

Answer (score 1):

look at the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` events for "total time", (<- those are also great for progressbars)

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

and `.ajaxSend()` and `.ajaxComplete()` events for "cumulative time" calculations.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

look at this code:

```
var totalTime = null;
var cachedTime = null;

function alertLoadingTime() {
    if(!totalTime) return;
    var loadingTime = totalTime / 1000;
    console.log("loaded " + loadingTime + " seconds");
}

function timingStart() {
    cachedTime = new Date;
}

function timingEnd() {
    var endTime = new Date;
    totalTime += endTime - cachedTime;
    cachedTime = null;
    alertLoadingTime();
}

$(document).ajaxStart(timingStart);

$(document).ajaxStop(timingEnd);
```

note that it will only account for time spent doing ajax calls and won't include the initial page loading time.

to time the parsing:

1. use the same functions as before but change `totalTime` to `totalParsingTime`. (Note: you can achieve this by changing `totalTime` to reference some other variable)
2. Call `timingStart()` right before you append the result of the ajax call to the dom tree.
3. Have the server add `timingEnd()` to the end of every response.

`totalTime` will then be set to the time it took to add everything to the DOM tree.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I am already using .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop for calculation of "total time". But instead of ajaxComplete, I am capturing start/end time of individual request on callback of "success" event. The reason for doing this is to break down the request time, before starting parsing. But once I have calculated time(Request + Parsing) for total requests, further adding the request + parsing time doesn't produce the results as per total time calculated using AJAX Start/Stop.

Comment: Please see the code which I have posted above and let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: looking at the code you added to your question: Why are you not using .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop()? This would make this code alot smaller and therefore also decrease the overhead of calculating how long it took

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am already using .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop, if you see at the end of my code. AJAX START and AJAX Stop are used to calculate overall complete time of process. Because AJAX Stop allows me to know when there are no other outstanding Ajax requests. But the problem I am trying to explain is about calculating time for individual requests. What are better ways to calculate time for individual requests? What is better way to break down time for individual request and parsing.

Comment: The problem with timing individual requests is that they may overlap, aka made at more or less the same time, hence asynchronous. If you just add up the time each individual request took, you most likely get a larger value than the time it took to complete all of them at once. Thats why i pointed you to the "total timing". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: you are correct for pointing me to total time for complete process. But, my another task is also to calculate how much "total time" it took for getting only data from server in client and how much total time client took for parsing it. As you see,I am using two arrays to capture start time for each request(when it is being sent to server) and end time (when it succeed,before starting parsing).And,under AJAX stop,I am not adding them,However I am subtracting the start time of "first request" from the "end time" of last request to calculate total time taken for fetching data from server.

Comment: If you want to know how long it took to "also" parse the content of the reply, you will need to call a function that does said computation at the last line of the reply from the server.

Comment: thank you very much for posting the code. could you please also help me in calculating parsing time taken for all ajax calls ? By parsing time, I mean that the time taken for parsing the responses received on Success event of all requests. 

For Example:  
5 AJAX Requests Sent to Server and corresponding 5 Responses are received. 

As soon, as the response is received it is parsed and placed on map.
In this example, how can I calculate how much time it took for parsing 5 responses excluding the time took for 5 requests being sent asynchronously?

Comment: thanks for updating the code once again. One last question: "As per your comment, Finally I have time values using "timingStart" and "timingEnd" for each response I received. let's say if my client sends five parallel requests to get data from server, then in that case, for calculating totalParsing time as per your code, I will have five different values from timingStart and timingEnd. So, What mathematical forumale I should use in this case with these five individual time stamps to measure total parsing time all together? I am pretty sure that I should not add them.

Comment: When doing the timing of "simultaneous parsing" and you want the total time it took, only update the "cachedTime" variable at the very first call. aka: if(!cachedTime) cachedTime = new Date. Also you will have to make sure to call timingEnd() only after the _last_ ajax call was done. That will give you a value that's as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

solution for you would to rely on jquery ajax callback methods

1. ajaxStart : Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins.
2. ajaxStop  : Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed including success and error callbacks

I have used the below code snippet in my application and it works perfectly fine to report page rendering time including ajaxs.

```
 var startTime = 0,endTime = 0;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        startTime = new Date();
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        endTime = new Date();
        console.log("total time required : ",endTime - startTime); //Total time in milliseconds including time spent in success or error callbacks
    });
```